# Simple examples for using while loops

Tags: language-agnostic

I'm trying to write up some examples to explain when a while loop should be used, and when a for loop should be used.

When looking for 'interesting' cases to show young and novice programmers, I realized that the vast majority of textbook examples for while loops will look something like this:

```
i = 0
while i < 10:
    do something
    i = i + 1
```

'do something' might be printing the odd numbers, squaring i, etc... However all these are obviously easier written with a for loop!

I'm looking for more interesting examples. They would have to be:

1. Suitable for younger programmers (e.g. not too much math such as numerical root finding or the sequence in Collatz conjecture)
2. Easier (or more intuitive) to be solved with while loops rather than for.
3. Have some real use to it (e.g. I could do `while random() < 0.95`, but what's a real use for this?)

The only example I could come up with is when getting a list input from the user one-by-one (e.g. numbers to be summed), but the user will have to terminate it with a special input, and also this seems pointless as the user could just say in advance how many entries there will be in the sequence.

Comment: Looks a bit too opinion-based.

Comment: I wasn't sure if it fits here, but could you tell me where you think this could fit?

Comment: I don't know that anywhere on the StackExchange network is a good fit for lists of examples. SO in particular is intended for questions that have right and wrong answers. It sounds like you're looking for a programming discussion forum. The [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) also mentions, "_Discussions are of course welcome in our real time web chat._"

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental difference between a `FOR` loop and a `WHILE` loop is that for a `FOR` loop, the number of iterations is bounded by a constant that is known before the loop starts, whereas for a `WHILE` loop, the number of iterations can be unbounded, unknown, or infinite.

As a result, a language offering only `WHILE` loops is Turing-complete, a language offering only `FOR` loops is not.

So, the first obvious thing that only a `WHILE` loop can do, is an infinite loop. Things that are easily modeled as infinite loops are, for example, a web server, a Netflix client, a game loop, a GUI event loop, or an operating system:

```
WHILE (r = nextHttpRequest):
    handle(r)
END

WHILE (p = nextVideoStreamPacket):
    frame = decode(p)
    draw(frame)
END

WHILE (a = playerAction):
    computeNextFrame(a)
END

WHILE (e = nextEvent):
    handle(e)
END

WHILE (s = sysCall):
    process(s)
END
```

A good example where the loop is not infinite, but the bound is not known in advance, is (as you already mentioned in your question) asking for user input. Something like this:

```
WHILE (askBoolean("Do you want to play again?")):
    playGame()
END
```

Another good example is processing a C-like string, where the length of the string is unknown but finite. This is the same situation for a linked list, or for *any* data structure where there is a notion of "next", but not a notion of "size", instead there is some sentinel value that marks the end (e.g. `NUL`-terminated strings in C) or a way to check whether there is a next element (e.g. `Iterator` in Java):

```
WHILE ((element = getNext()) != END_MARKER):
    process(element)
END

WHILE (hasNextElement):
    process(getNext())
END
```

There are also situations that *can* be handled with a `FOR` loop, but a `WHILE` loop is more elegant. One situation I can think of, is that the bound for the number of iterations is known in advance, it is constant, but the known bound is ridiculously large, and the actual number of iterations required is significantly less than the bound.

Unfortunately, I cannot come up with a good real-life example of this, maybe someone else can. A `FOR` loop for this will then typically look like this, in order to skip the iterations from the actual number of iterations up to the upper bound:

```
FOR (i FROM 1 TO $SOME_LARGE_UPPER_BOUND):
    IF (terminationConditionReached):
        NOOP()
    ELSE:
        doSomethingInteresting()
    END
END
```

Which would much better be expressed as

```
WHILE (NOT terminationConditionReached):
    doSomethingInteresting()
END
```

Using the `FOR` loop *could* make sense in this situation, if the value of `i` is of interest:

```
FOR (i FROM 1 TO $SOME_LARGE_UPPER_BOUND):
    IF (terminationConditionReached):
        NOOP()
    ELSE:
        doSomethingInterestingWithI(i)
    END
END
```

A last situation I can think of, where a `WHILE` loop is more appropriate than a `FOR` loop, even though the number of iterations is bounded by a known constant, is if that constant is not "semantically interesting" for the loop.

For example, a game loop for Tic-Tac-Toe only needs at most 9 moves, so it could be modeled as a `FOR` loop:

```
FOR (i FROM 1 TO 9):
    IF (player1Won OR player2Won):
        NOOP
    ELSE:
        makeMove()
    END
END
```

But, the number "9" is not really interesting here. It's much more interesting whether one player has one or the board is full:

```
WHILE (NOT (player1Won OR player2Won OR boardFull)):
    makeMove()
END
```

[Note: at least if playing against a child, this is also an example of the second-to-last situation, namely that the upper bound is known to be 9, but a lot of games will be shorter than 9 moves. However, I would still like to find an example for that, which is not *also* an example of a semantically un-interesting termination condition.]

So, we have two classes of situations here: one, where a `FOR` loop simply *cannot* be used (when the bound is unknown, non-existant, or infinite), and one, where a `FOR` loop can be used, but a `WHILE` loop is more *intention-revealing*.

Comment: Hmm, I don't really get it. Maybe you have a specific language in mind, but at least in C, C++, C# and Java, a `for` loop can do anything a `while` loop can.

Comment: Well, you happened to pick just *exactly* that subset of programming languages which have construct called `for` loop that is drastically different from what is commonly understood as a `for` loop. They are just `while` loops with strange syntax. It's really a pity that the designers of those languages chose to use the name of a well-known concept and apply it to something that is so different.

Comment: So Dennis Ritchie is to blame for having committed this crime almost 50 years ago :). All the others just copied him anyway, including the inventors of Javascript and Perl, by the way. I do agree with your comment except for the term "commonly understood". I would replace it with "historical meaning" or "still taught in some computer science classes". I do not mean to say that it is a good thing to misuse a common term for something different but after 50 years, we should just accept it.